# IE8 Using Google Font on ENTIRE Page Instead of Just Selected Text

Tags: css, fonts

All my web searches for Google Fonts with IE8 show people talking about google fonts just not loading or not showing up.  I don't have that problem.  Instead IE8 is loading my Google Font just fine, but its applying the font to ALL the type on the page!  Things seem to be fine in other browsers.  Is there some kind of glitch in my CSS that IE is choking on?

http://nbkclientsite.fuzzpopstudio.com/

Ok here's some of the relevant css:

```
body {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-family: Helvetica-Neue,Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    color: #444;
}

.contact-us-text {
    font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
    font-size: 150%;
    color: #2770b4;
}

.contact-us-phone {
    font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
    font-size: 175%;
}
```

Everything pertinent should be in just one style sheet.  You can easily view it with Firebug or Chrome's Inspector or whatever you want.

In FF and Chrome, everything is inheriting Helvetica or Arial as it should be.  But not in IE8.  You'd have to use Firebug and view the entire stylesheet if you want to see more.

Comment: Can you paste inn the relevant css you use in conjunction with the font (there are a ton of linked files in the html file).

Comment: Ok I edited the question and included what I could.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad.  I solved it.  When I looked at the element inspector in IE, I realized the bounding box was showing that the h3 element was encompassing the whole page.  SO I checked the markup and noticed the ending h3 tag was actually written as without the slash so it was acting as another opening h3.

FF and Webkit are just so forgiving.  LOL  IE spits on you when you make a mistake like that.  Apologies for asking with such a minor problem!  I just thought IE was choking on the font itself.